# Facebook is stripping params from my URL

Tags: facebook, url, parameters, send, query-string

This is a seriously annoying issue! Sure hope someone can point me in the right direction :)

I have a Facebook page, and on that page I have an app. Users can create a photo album based on their own photos and then email a link to their friends to come and view the album.

To send the link, I am trying to use Facebook's Send button. The link is a link back to the Facebook page with 2 parameters added on.

The first is 'sk' which contains the id of the app. This ensures the user is taken straight to the app's tab.

The second is 'app_data'. This is crucial as it contains the id of the photo gallery the user should be viewing.

However, it seems that Facebook is stripping these parameters from the URL in the Send Button message. I also tried using an URL shortener (both goo.gl and bit.ly). This works fine if the target is not a Facebook page, but with the link back to my app tab, Facebook seems to follow the link and replace the shortened link with the full url - stripping any parameters in the process!

There must be a way to share my app! :(

Any thoughts??

Thanks in advance,

Jon

Comment: Use Open Graph Protocol meta tags and URL encode the value of the URL in the meta tag.

Comment: I believe I am. The code I am using to generate the Send Button is:
`<div class="fb-send" data-href="MY_URLENCODED_LINK"></div>`
Although I may be missunderstanding exactly what you mean by meta tags here. I am using the HTML5 Send Plugin with the Javascript SDK